# Need help to convert formula into C#

Tags: c#

I got this formula,

> R/Rs = (5800/9500)<sup>2</sup>(2.512<sup>3.37</sup>)<sup>1/2</sup> = 1.76

How do I turn that into C# so that the value is 1.76.  Don't understand what you do with the 2 and 1/2?

Formula is from http://skyserver.sdss.org/dr5/en/proj/advanced/hr/radius1.asp

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: R_Rs = Math.Pow((double)5800/9500, 2.0) * Math.Pow( Math.Pow(2.512, 3.37), 0.5);

Comment: Why would you want to turn that equation into C#? Just take a calculator and see whether `(5800/9500)^2 * (2.5123.37)^(1/2)` equals `1.76` or not. If you want to write a program, and you're supposed to end up with `1.76`, just use that number as a literal constant: `const double rDividedByRs = 1.76;`.

Comment: It's the power of(5800/9500) and (2.512^3.37) ^.5  as written Mustafa

Comment: you actually need this formula R/Rs = (Ts/T)2(L/Ls)1/2

Comment: @stakx maybe he is trying to make a program that can calculate the radius of any given star? ... just a thought?... (and this one formula is just one step on his way)

Comment: @Jens: If that is true (and your assumption makes sense), then he should have asked about the actual formula *R/Rs = (Ts/T)^2 * (L/Ls)^(1/2)*, not about an equation where the variables have already been replaced with constant values and where nothing more needs to be done (except verify the result, perhaps).

Comment: Jens is correct, I'm trying to calculate a lot of star radiuses (3000+).  That above is the formula for Sirius, the dog star Radius.  If I could understand how the formula works then the rest is childs play, i just needed to know how.

Comment: @stakx Not necessarily... That depends on your process if narrowing down a problem and finding a solution, I have replaced data input with raw hard-coded values in code I couldn't get to work plenty of times before...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for `Math.Pow`

```
Math.Pow(5800d/9500d, 2)*Math.Pow(Math.Pow(2.512, 3.37),0.5);
```

And using `5800d/9500d` is important here (forcing double, one of the d's should do), as it would otherwise do integer division, leaving you with `0^2` and overall a big 0...

If you put this into a method taking the necessary double values that should be irrelevant.

Answer (score 2):

You can do :

```
double res = Math.Pow(5800 / 9500d, 2) *  Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(2.512, 3.37));
Console.WriteLine(res.ToString("0.00"));
```

output :

```
1.76
```

[Working demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/5X6Oju)

A power of `0.5` is a square root.

Answer (score 1):

Its

```
double i = 5800.0 / 9500;
i = Math.Pow(i, 2);

double x = Math.Pow(2.512, 3.37);
x = Math.Sqrt(x);

x = x * i;

x = Math.Round(x, 2);
```

[image]

OR

```
Math.Round(Math.Pow(5800.0 / 9500, 2) * Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(2.512, 3.37)), 2)
```

The trick is here is in the first line itself. If you will divide 5800 by 9500, it will return zero as division will happen in integers. So to do an actual division resulting in fractions one the the values have to be converted into decimal which i did by converting 5800 to 5800.0